# Is there any way to force https:// to be used for assets and still be able to define a theme CSS files in its .info file?

Tags: ssl, .info

I have a theme which defines its CSS files in its .info file, for example with a line like the following.

```
stylesheets[all][] = css/style.min.css
```

The site is accessed using https://, but for some reason, Drupal tries to load all the files via http://.

Is there any way to force Drupal to use https:// on assets and still be able to define a theme CSS files in its .info file?

Comment: Is it pure SSL? Or SSL/Non-SSL mix mode? Do you use [securepages](https://drupal.org/project/securepages) module?

Comment: That could be a caching issue where a client requesting a page over HTTPS gets a cached copy that was generated over HTTP and thus has HTTP links in it. I'm afraid I can't recommend an exact solution because it depends on the caching engine being used.

Comment: The standard Drupal page cache is keyed on the full url, i.e. the http and https versions of the page are different, so this wouldn't normally be an issue. If this is the issue, then it's likely because you have something in front of drupal that converts the https to http. If that's the case, they you'll want to be consistent about anonymous page access to your site, i.e. force all urls to be http or https.

Answer (score 4):

For a Drupal 7 site using Cloudflare CDN and a Bootstrap theme, this worked for me: Set the base URL in your settings.php file, without including http:// or https://.

```
$base_url = '//my.domain.name';
```

For another Drupal 7 site with a different theme, just removing `$base_url` worked.
In both cases, I needed the site to work with secure URLs and without.

Answer (score 2):

You might need to set the base URL in the settings.php file, specifying the URL scheme.

```
$base_url = 'https://my.domain.name';
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use [AdvAgg](http://drupal.org/project/advagg) as this will generate different aggregate filenames for http and https. If the issue is the cache then advagg will not fix it though.