# Site appears garbled after installing a SSL certificate on the server

Tags: 7, ssl

I installed a SSL certificate on the server. However, the site appears garbled under https://, which I need for several reason.

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of a duplicate of issues like [Is there any way to force https:// to be used for assets and still be able to define a theme CSS files in its .info file?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/80233/drupal-not-loading-theme-css-with-https)

@bharate is correct about the issue being caused by your assets not being loaded over https://.

It's likely caused by the `$base_url` in the *settings.php* file. Check to see if it includes the http:// as protocol and replace it with something like `$base_url = (drupal_is_https() ? 'https' : 'http') . '://www.example.org';` or `$base_url = '//demoflorida.com';`.

Using just *//* is protocol agnostic, so it will use whatever is asked for without any logic needed.

Answer (score -1):

Actually this is a problem of trying to load resources via http over https. You can check the link below for your website and you will see which elements/css are loaded via http
You will have to call them with https and your page should be fine.

https://www.whynopadlock.com/results/09ff9e5c-52d1-4299-80e5-3db45fe3aafd

Comment: You can equally check this in the browsers inspector, which will be showing errors in the console. But knowing that the assets aren't being requested with the right protocol doesn't explain why Drupal is doing it.

Comment: this is the key to the question, why is drupal requesting all these URLs over http? i got all those errors, hard errors, testing over whyno padlock, anybody can replicate this by invoking the site over https://